# Validate database backup For Innodb tables

Tags: mysql

Every fortnight, I take MySQL database dump from slave and then perform following steps as backup validation.

1. Number of Tables in every database.
2. Validate Schema of tables.
3. Validate random records for important tables.
4. An approximate(as its a backup) count of records in the table (only for MyISAM)

I am able to complete the activity. However since most of the tables are in InnoDB, I am not able to validate count properly. What solution can be there as count(*) is too slow in innodb?

Comment: Why are you validating every single backup? Don't you trust your tools? I agree on validate backups every while by restoring on a stating server but if you are not trusting your tools, you should change them and use something you can trust.

Comment: Are you restoring the SLAVE database dump output to another stand alone server - removed from your production / slave complex?

Comment: Its a backup from slave and we are using it as DR

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

SELECT database_name, table_name, last_update, n_rows
FROM mysql.innodb_table_stats;

immediately after DR?  To allow verification and avoid the long COUNT(*).

Comment: If you just need a confirming sum of the row count,
    SELECT SUM(n_rows) as Sum_n_rows  
    FROM mysql.innodb_table_stats
;

Comment: It will be done by other teams after say 10 hours

Comment: As long as the DR server has ONLY been used for DR staging, this could give you a quick list by table and then the SUM of the rows for all innodb tables on your DR you are prepping.  (The same queries on the SLAVE source of the backup - when the backup was taken 10 hours ago - could be used for the comparison.)  Give it a shot on your next cycle, please and let us know.